# Get main menu in to my search page

Tags: search

I'm using the built in search in Drupal 7. My problem is that I need to customize the search page. Is it possible to get the search results into a panel so that I can output my main menu and a few other elements? Now My search result page is very bare.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise your [search-results.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-results.tpl.php/7) by copying this file from the core search module and putting it into your theme directory. You can add your menu in where you like using code:

```
<div id="menu">
  <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu)); ?>
</div>
```

Also remember to clear your cache after making changes!

Comment: Thanks, but I solved it by using the structure -> page and search node. Activating it and then I got a panel for the search page. With the panel I displayed the content search results. Works like a charm :) My only problem now seems to be that you can't configure the search URL. Thanks for your reply and help by the way :)